# Formula Sum = 0

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

The sum still comes up zero and I have other sheets that are not having this issue:

[image: =SUM example]

Comment: Set your language properly to English US in your spreadsheet settings and in your Google account.

Answer (score 2):

Do a global replace of `$` for nothing then format ColumnD as Currency.

(You are trying to sum text.)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the fast response. How do I do a "global replace of the $"? I am not understanding why it's reading it as text when I formatted the cells to be Number